# wget/FTP downloading issue

Tags: ftp, wget, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using the command

> wget -r ftp://xyz/../

to download a directory on my wsl. It is a huge directory, so it takes hours to finish. My internet got disabled for a little bit, and the process terminated. I want to continue my download or restart downloading, skipping the files already downloaded.
How can I proceed with that?